# Trouble with loop (arduino)

Tags: c, arduino

I am trying to create a small stall at school using and arduino, 
the project is to scan items using a barcode scanner  enter the price and issue a receipt. the barcode scanner is connected to serial port and keypad and printer  are  connected via software serial.  I am using a 3.5" tv as the display. the items can be identified by the first 3 digits of the barcode. I want to include the item names  somewhere in the sketch and match and print them when the string starts with their number.
I have created a sketch with a lot of help from other forum users but the date is being repeatedly printed and not much else is happening. How do I make the date print only once. and also how do I buffer data from serial and software serial  before printing.

```
//#include <TVout.h>
//#include <video_gen.h>

//ARDUINO 1.0 COMPATIBLE ONLY!
//ARDUINO 1.0 COMPATIBLE ONLY!
#include <Time.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Thermal.h>
#include <Wire.h>
//TVout TV;
  int printer_RX_Pin = 3;
  int printer_TX_Pin = 4;
  int incomingByte = 0;
  Thermal printer(printer_RX_Pin, printer_TX_Pin, 19200);

  String readString;    // a string to hold incoming data
   //SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);
  void setup(){
    //TV.begin(PAL,120,96);
    // TV.select_font(font6x8);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //mySerial.begin(9600);
    setSyncProvider(RTC.get);  
    // if (timeStatus() != timeSet )  
    // Serial.println("Unable to sync with the RTC");
    // else
    //  Serial.println("RTC has set the system time"); 
    //tv.print(scan item)  ???
    //ITEM SCANNED GETS STORED INTO string.Readstring
    //tv print (enter donation  Amount)
    //INPUT FROM KEYPAD GETS STORED INTO  BUFFER1 (KEYPAD IS HOOKED UP TO SOFTWARE SERIAL          PINS)
    //THEN PRINTER PRINTS TITLE  (MAYBE BETTER TO WAIT FOR ALL INPUT BEFORE PRINTING)

    printer.justify('C'); 

    //sets text justification (right, left, center) accepts 'L', 'C', 'R'
    printer.setSize('L'); // set type size, accepts 'S', 'M', 'L'
    printer.println("School Feast "); //print line
    printer.setSize('M'); // set type size, accepts 'S', 'M', 'L'
    printer.println("My Stall"); //print line 
    printer.println("My Town");
    printer.feed(); //advance one line
    printer.println(" My Country");
    printer.feed(); //advance one line 
  }

  void serialRead() {

     while (Serial.available()) {
        delay(10);  
        if (Serial.available() >0) {
        char c = Serial.read();
        readString += c;};
       }
  }
  void loop() {
    // THEN TIME GETS PRINTED 
     tmElements_t tm;

     if (RTC.read(tm)) {
       Serial.print(" ");
       print2digits(tm.Hour);
       Serial.write(':');
       print2digits(tm.Minute);
       Serial.write(':');
       print2digits(tm.Second);
       Serial.print("        ");
       Serial.print(tm.Day);
       Serial.write('/');
       Serial.print(tm.Month);
       Serial.write('/');
       Serial.print(tmYearToCalendar(tm.Year));
       Serial.println();
       printer.print(" ");

       print2digits(tm.Hour);
       printer.write(':');
       print2digits(tm.Minute);
       printer.write(':');
       print2digits(tm.Second);
       printer.print("        ");
       printer.print(tm.Day);
       printer.write('/');
       printer.print(tm.Month);
       printer.write('/');
       printer.print(tmYearToCalendar(tm.Year));
       printer.println();
     } else {
        if (RTC.chipPresent()) {
           Serial.println("The DS1307 is stopped.  Please run the SetTime");
           Serial.println("example to initialize the time and begin running.");
           Serial.println();
        } else {
           Serial.println("DS1307 read error!  Please check the circuitry.");
           Serial.println();
        }
       delay(9000);
  }
   delay(1000);
}

void print2digits(int number) {
   if (number >= 0 && number < 10) {
     Serial.write('0');
   }
   Serial.print(number);
   if (Serial.available() > 0) {
       readString = "";
       serialRead();
       String Item = readString.substring(0,3);
       //THEN ITEM PRINT( IDENTIFY ITEM BY FIRST 3 CHARACTERS OF STRING, HOW??)
       Serial.print(Item);
       printer.print(Item);
       Serial.println();{
       //THEN PRINT DONATION AMOUNT(INPUT FROM SOFTWARE SERIAL)
      //printer.print(software.serial buffer)
      //printer. print("GBP"); 
      //clear display
      //tv.clear

    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly in order to make it readable.

Comment: First time posting on this forum, I am not sure what you mean, could you tell me how to format @PaulR

Comment: means `(RTC.read(tm)` always read date and then it print right?

Comment: thanks for the edit @Gerald Schneider

Comment: so why you not move `if (RTC.read(tm)) {...}` to `setup` and leave else part in `loop`?